# change background when viewing on mobile device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

http://new.931thefan.com/

When viewing on a mobile device I want the listen live button under the logo, which is working. I want to eliminate the background when viewing on the mobile device and I want the color background to be black. This isn't working. I also want to adjust the height as there is too much space between listen live and menu.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #header { 
        background-color: black; 
        background-image:none; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to have a look at your website and I noticed 2 things:

1.
The css style you should use into your @media query to overwrite the default behavior and get it working is background: black; instead then background-color: black;

2.
In this moment doesn't seems to be any @media query on your css related to the (max-width: 400px)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have changed to the below but I can't get it to work @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #header{
   background: #000000;
   }

  #listenlive{
   margin-top : 300px;
}
}

Comment: looking at your website (inspect element) I can see the media query 

@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 768px)
#header {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

on the file skeleton.css, but nothing related to  (max-width: 400px) or  (max-width: 479px)...

Where did you put it?

Comment: I placed in style.css but now I see skeleton.css. Where do I place your code? I tried placing under  /* Note: Design for a width of 480px */

    @media handheld, screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {      but no luck

Comment: Add this: @media handheld, screen and (max-width: 400px) {
#header {
    background: black;
} } at the end of skeleton.css

Comment: I still don't see the media query with (max-width: 400px), can you please add the lines from my previous comment in order to let me check live?

Comment: Great, if you resize the browser windows under 400px you can see that the  background will change now, if it doesn't show up on mobile, you probably you are watching at a device bigger than 400px and you should set the query at 480px

Comment: Perfect I see now. Thanks for your help